# Constraints on SMTP Message-Id?

Tags: smtp

Are there constraints on the length and/or format of SMTP message-id's? I.e.: How long may they be, and are only certain characters allowed? (I plan to use only ASCII, but I fear that there may even be ASCII characters which aren't allowed.)

RFC822 defines this, but are there updated RFCs or common real-World aspects (such as common bugs in mail software) which should be considered?

Comment: Current spec is RFC 5322:  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.6.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The updated RFC is RFC2822.

As of characters allowed, it basically

```
::alpha::|::digit::|[!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~.]
```

(It's also possible to quote literals).

It has to contain @ separating "local part" and "domain part". It **MUST** be **globally** unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an example, you could look at the code for the [email.utils.make_msgid](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html) Python library function.