# Maximum internet email Message-ID length

Tags: validation, email, maxlength

I'm looking for the maximum character length allowed for an internet Message-ID field for validation purposes within an application.  I've reviewed sources such as [RFC-2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) and [Wikipedia "Message-ID"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID) as well as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594330/constraints-on-smtp-message-id), among other various places.  The closest answer I can find is "998 characters" because that is the maximum length that the specification allows for each line in an internet message (from RFC-2822), and the Message-ID field cannot be multiple lines.

Is 998 characters the definitive answer?  Is there no such limit?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If there's one thing I've learned about email, it must be that it's a massively distributed system for [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing) email software. That is, no matter what the RFCs say, you will find emails violating them, some email software coping and some failing. I think most will limp along with the [robustness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) in mind.

With that out of the way, I think the maximum RFC compliant Message-ID length is 995 characters.

The maximum line length per the RFC you cite is 998 characters. That would include the "Message-ID:" field name, but you can do line folding between the field name and the field body. The line containing the actual Message-ID would then contain a space (the folding whitespace), "<", Message-ID, and ">". Semantically, the angle brackets are not part of the Message-ID. Therefore you end up with a maximum of 998 - 3 = 995 characters.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there's no limit

[RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) defines these productions:

```
message-id      =       "Message-ID:" msg-id CRLF

msg-id          =       [CFWS] "<" id-left "@" id-right ">" [CFWS]

id-left         =       dot-atom-text / no-fold-quote / obs-id-left

obs-id-left     =       local-part

local-part      =       dot-atom / quoted-string / obs-local-part

quoted-string   =       [CFWS]
                        DQUOTE *([FWS] qcontent) [FWS] DQUOTE
                        [CFWS]

CFWS            =       *([FWS] comment) (([FWS] comment) / FWS)

FWS             =       ([*WSP CRLF] 1*WSP) /   ; Folding white space
```

So `id-left` can be `local-part` which can be `quoted-string` (and thus have multiple `FWS`)
so you can fold it as many times as needed to fit any arbitrary
length of payload and still comply with the restrictions given
by the RFC.

Comment: Of course, if one chooses to accept arbitrary messages conforming to RFC-822, it doesn't even impose a maximum line length.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite wilde guess, but i would say 2000 chars is more than enough and here is why:

The only related length requirement I found is message line can't be longer than 998 chars. My wild assumption would be this: Message id should be able to be within one line of message and this limit is 998 chars. From message ids i saw during my time it's not that long. So from all the uncertainty i would say 1000 chars is very "safe" minimum range and like 2000 should cover any scenario if there is any kind of "structural overhead" of some data shape.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822

[image]